# Mac OS X Lion Terminal SSH connection sharing error

Tags: ssh, terminal, connection-sharing, macbook-air

I sometimes get this error when I try to ssh to a remote host:

```
mux_client_request_session: read from master failed: Broken pipe
```

I'm using Macbook Air OS X Lion with this in ~/.ssh/config:

```
ControlMaster auto
ControlPath /tmp/ssh_mux_%h_%p_%r

ControlPersist 4h

ForwardAgent yes

Host [ex]
    HostName [example.com]
    User [somedude]
```

The error above happens when I do:

```
ssh ex
```

Terminal hangs for ~1 min and then displays:

```
mux_client_request_session: read from master failed: Broken pipe
somedude@example.com's password:
```

I type in my password and it's ok. And if I open another Terminal tab, connection sharing is ok too. How can I fix this? It's not terrible, but it's annoying.

Comment: Can you log into any other remote machines from your macbook air? Can any other machines login to somedude@example.com?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You have `ControlPersist` enabled. My educated guess is that the following happens:

1. You have connection to example.com
2. Logout, but because `ControlPersist` is enabled, session is kept open for future connections.
3. Something goes wrong with your network connection, and thus, persistent connection breaks.
4. When you run `ssh somedude@example.com` again, it tries to reuse connection from step 2, and opens a new connection after timeout.

No separate option for this timeout is available, according to `man ssh_config`. To avoid this, don't use `ControlPersist`. Additionally, I highly recommend using public key login, if possible. You can still have passphrase for your public key, but public key effectively prevents brute-forcing your password over SSH connection.

Additionally, you should not store control files under `/tmp`. Those should/must be secured, and for that, for example `~/.ssh/master/ssh_mux_%h_%p_%r` is way better location. Of course, if you're the only user of your laptop (?), that's not too big issue.